# Equivalence between CGLMP inequality and CHSH inequality

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, probability, bells-inequality

In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0106024) paper, they claim that the inequality $$I = P(A_1 = B_1) + P(B_1 = A_2 + 1) + P(A_2 = B_2) + P(B_2 = A_1) \leq 3$$ is equivalent to the CHSH inequality $$|E(A_1,B_1) - E(A_2,B_1) + E(A_2,B_2) + E(A_1,B_2)| \leq 2.$$

I tried to show that these two inequalities are indeed equivalent. For that purpose, I started by writing $E(A_i,B_j)$ as $$P(A_i=B_j) - P(A_i=B_j+1) = 2P(A_i=B_j) - 1,$$ since $$P(A_i=B_j+1) = 1 - P(A_i=B_j).$$

Then, I wrote $I$ as $$I=\frac{1}{2} [E(A_1,B_1) - E(A_2,B_1) + E(A_2,B_2) + E(A_1,B_2)] + 2,$$ such that I obtained that $I\leq 3$ is equivalent to $$E(A_1,B_1) - E(A_2,B_1) + E(A_2,B_2) + E(A_1,B_2) \leq 2.$$

However, according to [[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0106024)], $I \leq 3$ should also imply that $$E(A_1,B_1) - E(A_2,B_1) + E(A_2,B_2) + E(A_1,B_2) \geq - 2.$$ How can I show this part?

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: ... and defining the quantities you use.

Comment: A funny calculation is allowing for angle dependence in the domain of the covariance : $$1/(p|a-b|)\int_0^{p|a-b|}sign(\cos(a-x)sign(\cos(b-x))dx$$. Deriving wrt p gives the maximal value of the covariance. For example $$cov(0,\pi/4)\leq\pi/4\Rightarrow CHSH\leq \pi$$

Comment: Erratum : it gives covariance lower equals 1.